# Get last date in each month of a time series pandas

Tags: python, pandas, zipline

Currently I'm generating a DateTimeIndex using a certain function, `zipline.utils.tradingcalendar.get_trading_days`. The time series is roughly daily but with some gaps.

My goal is to get the last date in the `DateTimeIndex` for each month.

`.to_period('M')` & `.to_timestamp('M')` don't work since they give the last day of the month rather than the last value of the variable in each month.

As an example, if this is my time series I would want to select '2015-05-29' while the last day of the month is '2015-05-31'.

['2015-05-18', '2015-05-19', '2015-05-20', '2015-05-21',
               '2015-05-22', '2015-05-26', '2015-05-27', '2015-05-28',
               '2015-05-29', '2015-06-01']

Comment: Sorry won't `df.groupby([df.index.year,df.index.month]).last()` give what you want?

Comment: No, that doesn't unfortunately. Take a look at my post for an example.

Comment: I'm not sure why Ed's comment won't work.  Your post first converts to a period, whereas Ed's comment just looks at the last trading day in any given month for any given year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Condla's answer came closest to what I needed except that since my time index stretched for more than a year I needed to groupby by both month and year and then select the maximum date. Below is the code I ended up with.

```
# tempTradeDays is the initial DatetimeIndex
dateRange = []  
tempYear = None  
dictYears = tempTradeDays.groupby(tempTradeDays.year)
for yr in dictYears.keys():
    tempYear = pd.DatetimeIndex(dictYears[yr]).groupby(pd.DatetimeIndex(dictYears[yr]).month)
    for m in tempYear.keys():
        dateRange.append(max(tempYear[m]))
dateRange = pd.DatetimeIndex(dateRange).order()
```

Comment: Like it. But maybe there is a pandas inhouse solution for this nowdays...

Answer (score 6):

Suppose your data frame looks like this

[original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAyo2.png)

Then the following Code will give you the last day of each month.

```
df_monthly = df.reset_index().groupby([df.index.year,df.index.month],as_index=False).last().set_index('index')
```

[transformed_dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6iAA.png)

This one line code does its job :)

Answer (score 4):

My strategy would be to group by month and then select the "maximum" of each group:

If "dt" is your DatetimeIndex object:

```
last_dates_of_the_month = []
dt_month_group_dict = dt.groupby(dt.month)
for month in dt_month_group_dict:
    last_date = max(dt_month_group_dict[month])
    last_dates_of_the_month.append(last_date)
```

The list "last_date_of_the_month" contains all occuring last dates of each month in your dataset. You can use this list to create a DatetimeIndex in pandas again (or whatever you want to do with it).

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but all existing answers here aren't perfect. This is the solution I came up with (assuming that date is a sorted index), which can be even written in one line, but I split it for readability:

```
month1 = pd.Series(apple.index.month)
month2 = pd.Series(apple.index.month).shift(-1)
mask = (month1 != month2)
apple[mask.values].head(10)
```

Few notes here:

- Shifting a datetime series requires another `pd.Series` instance (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47502584/712995))
- Boolean mask indexing requires `.values` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46374860/712995))

---

By the way, when the dates are the *business days*, it'd be easier to use resampling: `apple.resample('BM')`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the answer is not needed anymore, but while searching for an answer to the same question I found maybe a simpler solution:

```
import pandas as pd 

sample_dates = pd.date_range(start='2010-01-01', periods=100, freq='B')
month_end_dates = sample_dates[sample_dates.is_month_end]
```

Comment: OP clearly states "if this is my time series I would want to select '2015-05-29' while the last day of the month is '2015-05-31'."  Your solution would miss 2015-05-29 since it is not a month-end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to create a new diff column where the value 1 points to the change from one month to the next.

```
     df['diff'] = np.where(df['Date'].dt.month.diff() != 0,1,0)
```